# Performing a segue from a class in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, segue

I have a view named AppPurchaseViewController that calls a function from the IAPManagerm class. After my receipt is validated as a in app purchase, I want to perform a segue using the segue id that I set up in my AppPurchaseViewController class. When I try that, Xcode gives me an error that says "AppPurchaseViewController: 0x117e70ae0>) has no segue with identifier". My code is below

```
case .purchased:
print("Purchased")

self.validateReceipt(completion: {(success) in
if success {
SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
}
else {

}
//here is where I want to perform the segue
AppPurchaseViewController().performSegue(withIdentifier:'open', sender:nil)
})
```

Can someone point me in the right direction to get this view to load?

Comment: Are you using a storyboard? If so, the storyboard identifier of that segue needs to be set therein to "open", like you have it. And if not, then show the code wherein you set up the segue.

Comment: Is this code being called from within IAPManager?

Comment: Hi David. This code is being called within IAPManager

Answer (score 2):

At the top of your IAPManager class, you should declare an instance of type AppPurchaseViewController, like so:

```
var appPurchaseVC: AppPurchaseViewController!
```

Whenever you declare your IAPManager, assuming it is from within the AppPurchaseViewController class, you should set the IAPManager’s appPurchaseVC value.

```
var iapManager = IAPManager()
iapManager.appPurchaseVC = self
```

Then from within your IAPManager, at a later time when you want to perform the segue, call:

```
appPurchaseVC.performSegue(withIdentifier:'open', sender:nil)
```

This ensures that you are calling `performSegue` from the storyboard instance of AppPurchaseViewController. In your current code, you are creating a new instance of AppPurchaseViewController (I.e., not the one in your storyboard) and then calling `performSegue`. Because this new instance isn’t in our storyboard, it naturally cannot perform a segue to another view controller in the storyboard.